# Problems running ktlint from module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Updated [ktlint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57359834/6387618), started tasks, everything works as it should.

Here is my code from `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
    ktlint
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ktlint "com.pinterest:ktlint:0.34.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //...another dependencies
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    ktlint
}

task ktlint(type: JavaExec, group: "verification") {
    description = "Check Kotlin code style."
    classpath = configurations.ktlint
    main = "com.pinterest.ktlint.Main"
    args "src/**/*.kt"
    // to generate report in checkstyle format prepend following args:
    // "--reporter=plain", "--reporter=checkstyle,output=${buildDir}/ktlint.xml"
    // see https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint#usage for more
}
check.dependsOn ktlint

task ktlintFormat(type: JavaExec, group: "formatting") {
    description = "Fix Kotlin code style deviations."
    classpath = configurations.ktlint
    main = "com.pinterest.ktlint.Main"
    args "-F", "src/**/*.kt"
}
```

But when I change the dependency to my module **custom_ktlint_rules**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ktlint project(':custom_ktlint_rules')
```

and run the task, I get this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:ktlint'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:ktlint'.
>   >     Could not resolve project :custom_ktlint_rules.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :app
>   >     Cannot choose between the following variants of project :custom_ktlint_rules:
>   >           - debugRuntimeElements
>   >           - releaseRuntimeElements
>   >         All of them match the consumer attributes:
>   >           - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements':
>   >               - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>   >               - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>   >               - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Apk' but
>   >     wasn't required.
>   >               - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
>   >               - Found org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'androidJvm' but wasn't required.
>   >           - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements':
>   >               - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>   >               - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>   >               - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Apk' but
>   >     wasn't required.
>   >               - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
>   >               - Found org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'androidJvm' but wasn't required.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 0s

My `build.gradle` for separate module is here:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    compileOnly "com.pinterest:ktlint:$ktlintVersion"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version? The problem is solved in recent versions

Comment: @GOVINDDIXIT ext.ktlintVersion = '0.29.0'

Comment: try this version '0.34.2 '

Comment: I have added an answer, Hope it will solve this issue.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74249501/6236959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is how i resolved my problem and run ktlint

First I was update my root `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jlleitschuh.gradle:ktlint-gradle:8.2.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: "org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint" // Version should be inherited from parent

    // Optionally configure plugin
    ktlint {
        debug = true
    }

    dependencies {
        ktlintRuleset project(":custom_ktlint_rules")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And in `build.gradle` added next dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
    compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime")
    compileOnly("com.pinterest.ktlint:ktlint-core:0.34.2")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest version `0.34.2` This problem is resolved in recent versions.

For more details look [here](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0121---2017-11-13)

Use [this](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint) library for ktlint `"com.pinterest:ktlint:0.34.2"`

Try this:

```
ktlint project(':custom_ktlint_rules', configuration: 'default')
```

Comment: i tried, and get another error with this changes: `ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.shyiko.ktlint:ktlint-core:0.34.2
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: custom_ktlint_rules`

Comment: use this library for ktlint "com.pinterest:ktlint:0.34.2", replace the existing one with this

Comment: Updated ktlint, started tasks, everything works as it should.
But the link with my module does not work, I can not understand why. I'll update the question now. But for the comment with the version of I put a plus, thanks

Comment: Updated question. Now it seems like everything is well described

Comment: Updated, Try and let me know if it helps

Comment: `Gradle DSL method not found: 'project()'
Possible causes:
The project 'target-list' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.4.2 and sync project

The project 'target-list' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin`

Comment: which version of gradle are you using?

Comment: Hi @Morozov As the problem for which you have asked the question at the first place is already solved by the above solution. I will suggest you to add new question for new problems rather than updating the same question which is an ideal way all good developer follows. I think you are wrongly implemented the things. I will suggest you to go through this: https://goobar.io/2019/07/25/adding-ktlint-to-your-kotlin-project/ Hope this will help you.

Comment: I will no longer update the question
but I can't be sure that a solution has been found
now try to solve the issue and if they can unsubscribe here if it helped your decision, thank you.
the link you provided helps to connect the plugin, no more.